# Added a lot of var javascript into an array and remove a specific array that has inserted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code looked like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function () {
        addRow();
        /*DECLARE AN EMPTY ARRAY*/
        var myArrays=[];

        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var type = tr.find("#type").val();
        var item = tr.find("#item").val();
        var damage = tr.find("#damage").val();
        var repair = tr.find("#repair").val();
        var remarks = tr.find("#remarks").val();
        var manhour = tr.find("#manhour").val();

        /*How to push that vars to myArrays*/

    });
```

Coz I am on learning PHP and for simple ajax, I have expectation like this :

```
Array
(
   [1] => Array
    (
        [TYPE] =>     
        [ITEM] =>     
        [DAMAGE] =>     
        [REPAIR] =>     
        [REMARKS] =>    
        [MANHOUR] =>    
    )

)
```

And if the user click this button again, it will be append the array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [TYPE] =>     
        [ITEM] =>     
        [DAMAGE] =>     
        [REPAIR] =>     
        [REMARKS] =>    
        [MANHOUR] =>    
    ) 
  [2] => Array
    (
        [TYPE] =>     
        [ITEM] =>     
        [DAMAGE] =>     
        [REPAIR] =>     
        [REMARKS] =>    
        [MANHOUR] =>    
    )


)
```

For the help, it so appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all solution. Now, I get stucked if I want to remove an array that have pushed,
I have code like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        /*Remove an array*/

    });
```

For ex, if I delete a first row, it will be remove first array. So, the array now looked like this :

```
Array
(
  [2] => Array
    (
        [TYPE] =>     
        [ITEM] =>     
        [DAMAGE] =>     
        [REPAIR] =>     
        [REMARKS] =>    
        [MANHOUR] =>    
    )


)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate an object and push the object to the array.

```
myArrays.push({
    TYPE: type,
    ITEM: item,     
    DAMAGE: damage,
    REPAIR: repair
    REMARKS: remarks,
    MANHOUR: manhour
});
```

Answer (score 0):

array push,

```
var myArrays=[];

        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var type = tr.find("#type").val();
        var item = tr.find("#item").val();
        var damage = tr.find("#damage").val();
        var repair = tr.find("#repair").val();
        var remarks = tr.find("#remarks").val();
        var manhour = tr.find("#manhour").val();
myArrays.push(tr )
.push(type )
.push(item )
.push(damage )
.push(repair )
.push(remarks )
.push(manhour );
```